# Android Talkback with RecyclerView inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, talkback

Image 1: The order TalkBack is currently reading in.

Image2: The order I would like TalkBack to follow.

I have a (vertical) RecyclerView with a (horizontal) RecyclerView inside of it. When attempting to use TalkBack, it scrolls horizontally through the visible parts of the RecyclerView elements rather than "finishing" all the views within one of the elements. I believe it's because the views are offscreen. But it makes for a super bizarre screen reader experience.

How do I make TalkBack finish reading the View it's in before moving on to the next?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Hi! Did you have any luck solving this please? Facing the same issue here 

Comment: Sorry no, never did figure it out. We descoped that particular issue. If you figure it out I'd love to know!